# Can I use RazorEngine in the template.cshtml?

Tags: razor, resources, razorengine

Here I have a resource file with text string into, like this:

> Dear @Model.SupporterName, @Model.ConsumerName from company
>   @Model.ConsumerCompany open acess to next license aggrements for team
>   work

On my View.cshtml I use that string from resource

```
<tr>
    <td class="free-text">
        @Resources.ActivatedBodyText
    </td>
</tr>
```

And RunCompile with specified Model.

BUT!

When all rendered, html file looks like:

[Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBqu8.png)

How can I render string from resources using RazorEngine????

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Comment: I there is related question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38303160/how-to-use-razor-to-process-dynamic-templates-included-in-web-page

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

**Result:**

[image: ParsedTextResult]

**Controller Action:**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string templateStr = Resources.ActivatedBodyText;
        Template product = new Template() { SupporterName = "Support1", ConsumerCompany = "Company1", ConsumerName = "Consumer1" };
        string pattern = @"\@Model\.(\w+)";
        Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
        MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(templateStr);
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            string capture = match.Groups[1].Value;
            string propertyvalue = product.GetType().GetProperty(capture).GetValue(product).ToString();
            templateStr = templateStr.Replace(match.ToString(), propertyvalue);
        }
        ViewBag.templateStr = templateStr;
        return View();
    }
```

**Description:**

1. Found all instance of "@Model." within the resource string and captured the property name using regular expressions
2. Looped through each of the matches and obtained the property values via reflection
3. Replaced the matched "@Model..." expression with the value of the property
4. Passed the new template string to the view via ViewBag